# Migration Windows Store App based on 8.1. does it has backward compatibility with 8?

Tags: migration, windows-store-apps, backwards-compatibility

As you know Microsoft Build conference is running on this week.

I hardly find whether 8.1 based store app has backward compatibility with 8 based app or not.

If I upgrade my Store App (**what if I make update on preview period**) to 8.1 based template, does it run on Windows 8 without problem?
Or, do I need to treat some special cases? I already know that Snapped ViewState was removed.

If there's no problem, please link relative article on answer. I could not find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, once you migrate an app to Windows 8.1 Preview, the minimum OS version in the manifest will be set to 6.3.0 which will only allow it to run on 8.1. Windows 8 apps, on the other hand, will run on both 8 and 8.1.

There are more migration issues than the view state matters. See //build 2013 talk http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-077 for the details.

Comment: Sounds pretty bad. Is there anything like modernizr that allows you to plug the missing API with some kind of emulator? Let's face it here win 8 adoption has been weak in the tablet space, I am not keen in further halving my audience by this lack of compatibility.