# Develop a windows store app for Windows 8 and Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

is it possible to develop an app for windows 8 and it will run on windows 8.1 normally? what about the validation in the store? and its visibility in the store for users who have windows 8.1 on their pcs?

why visual studio 2013 professional version is supported by windows 8 and not visual studio 2013 express edition for windows?

if we developp a library in windows phone 8, could we reuse it in Windows 8.1 application? (specifically its validation in the store?)
thx for ur answers

Answer (score 2):

- ***Will a Win8 app run on Win8.1?***

Check this question here on SO: [Migration Windows Store App based on 8.1. does it has backward compatibility with 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378498/migration-windows-store-app-based-on-8-1-does-it-has-backward-compatibility-wit)

Basically, the answer is `YES`. But not the other way around. Windows 8.1 apps will not work on Windows 8. So the visibility in the store depends on the targeted version of the app and the version that is running. Win 8.1 users will see both and Win 8 users only see Win 8 apps.

- ***VS2013 Express on Windows 8.1 only?***

Depends on the type of VS you want. Check the [**Visual Studio Express**](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) page and decide which version you want. For example `Express 2013 for Windows` will only work on Windows 8.1, while `Express 2013 for Windows Desktop` will also work on Windows 8.

- ***Windows Phone 8 to Windows 8?***

Channel9 Always had interesting posts about development and for this case too. Check the page [**Building Apps for Both Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 Jump Start**](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Both-Windows-8-and-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start) for more information about developing for both platforms.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, i want visual studio for Windows (the one to develop windows store apps)

Comment: Then you will indeed need Windows 8.1. If you're still using Windows 8 you can upgrade to 8.1 and then install VS2013 for Windows.

Comment: I can not upgrade my windows 8 because it is Entreprise version :/